# Creating one-many realationship data using REST API's and Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So i’ve got 2 tables that form a one-to-many relationship
A owner can own multiple pets

```
class Owner(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "owner"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    address = db.Column(db.String())
    pets = db.relationship('Pet', backref='owner', lazy=True) 
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.id}','{self.name},'{self.items}')"

class Pet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "pets"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('owner.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.id}','{self.name}','{self.owner_id}')"
```

And one of the API calls is to create a pet:

```
@app.route("/createPet", methods=["POST"])
def create_pet():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    print(json_data)

    new_pet = Pet(name = json_data["name"], age = json_data["age"], owner = json_data["owner"])
    db.session.add(new_pet)
    db.session.commit()

    response = "new pet added" + str(json_data)

    return response
```

I then POST a json body (the owner is already in the database)

```
{
    "name":"Snowball 2",
    "age":4,
    "owner":"homer"
}
```

However, when run it looks like the application crashes when trying to input a pet from a json value

When using flask-sqlalchemy, you could get away with a pet being created from a object where one of the values is backreferencing another model (such as the owner model)

```
owner = (name=”homer, address=”42 evergreen terrace”)
pet = (name=”snowball 2”, age=4, owner=”homer”)
```

I'm assuming the “new_pet” db object is at fault but im not sure how to fix how the json is being read / run

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to pass in a unique identifier for the owner e.g their primary key in the database. In your view function you can then query the owner and add them to the one to many relationship.

**Working example:**

```
# Payload:
{
    "name":"Snowball 2",
    "age":4,
    "owner_id":1
}


@app.route("/createPet", methods=["POST"])
def create_pet():
    json_data = request.get_json()

    owner = Owner.query.get(json_data["owner_id"])
    if owner is None:
      abort(400, description="Owner not found")

    new_pet = Pet(name=json_data["name"], age = json_data["age"])
    owner.pets.append(new_pet)
    db.session.commit()

    response = "new pet added" + str(json_data)

    return response
```

Alternatively, you can add the owner to pets like below. Note that owner is referencing a sqlalchemy model object.

`new_pet = Pet(name=json_data["name"], age = json_data["age"], owner=owner)`

Or you could save the owner id directly

```
new_pet = Pet(name=json_data["name"], age = json_data["age"], owner_id=json_data["owner_id"])
```